# Why can't I find the type 'System.Char&' when upgrading to .NET 7 Preview?

Tags: .net-7.0

I am upgrading a web project to [.NET 7 Preview 7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-7-preview-7/) and Visual Studio 2022 Preview 17.4.  On startup, I receive the following exception:

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Char&' from assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0 ...'

It seems like I've setup .NET 7 incorrectly, but how?

`dotnet --list-sdks` shows the following row:

```
7.0.100-preview.7.22377.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

The "Framework" for my project shows the proper version:

[image: AspNetCore Framework Properties]

The full exception is shown here:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Char&' from assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.MakeByRef()
   at System.RuntimeType.MakeByRefType()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ParameterBindingMethodCache.<FindTryParseMethod>g__Finder|15_0(Type type)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelMetadata.InitializeTypeInformation()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadata..ctor(IModelMetadataProvider provider, ICompositeMetadataDetailsProvider detailsProvider, DefaultMetadataDetails details, DefaultModelBindingMessageProvider modelBindingMessageProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadataProvider.CreateModelMetadata(DefaultMetadataDetails entry)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadataProvider.CreateCacheEntry(ModelMetadataIdentity key)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadataProvider.GetMetadataForParameter(ParameterInfo parameter, Type modelType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.DefaultApplicationModelProvider.CreateParameterModel(ParameterInfo parameterInfo)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.DefaultApplicationModelProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ApplicationModelProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ApplicationModelFactory.CreateApplicationModel(IEnumerable`1 controllerTypes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.UpdateCollection()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Subscribe>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.Subscribe()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.GetOrCreateDataSource(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllers(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at MyApp.Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__7_0(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints) in C:\Source\MyApp\Startup.cs:line 81
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
   at MyApp.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in C:\Source\MyApp\Startup.cs:line 79
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

This occurs in some very boilerplate web startup code:

```cs
public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   app.UseRouting();
   app.UseMiddleware<AddHostHeader>();
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {
       endpoints.MapControllers();      // <-- Exception occurs in here.
       endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
       endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
   });
   // .. snip ..
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that there is a discussion on this topic on the [AspNetCore Github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43256).  (Currently unresolved, frown.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This was a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43256#issuecomment-1238892555) in preview versions of .NET 7.  It is fixed in .NET 7 RC2.

For completeness, this was the result of having a by-reference parameter in a non-ASP.NET "controller."  That is, a class named "MyController" (that was part of an unrelated MVC pattern) was being automatically registered by convention as an ASP.NET controller, which cannot have by-ref parameters.